# IE hides div element when certain class is used, works fine in chrome/firefox, does anyone have information on this error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, oracle-apex

So, I am using oracle apex and I use JavaScript to populate a div tab and add the element to a hidden region on the current page. The resulting HTML is below:

```
 <div class="t-ButtonRegion **t-Form--floatLeft** t-ButtonRegion--noPadding t-ButtonRegion--noUI" id="main_details" role="group" aria-labelledby="main_details_heading">
  <div class="t-ButtonRegion-wrap">
    <div class="t-ButtonRegion-col t-ButtonRegion-col--left"><div class="t-ButtonRegion-buttons"></div></div>
    <div class="t-ButtonRegion-col t-ButtonRegion-col--content">
      <h2 class="t-ButtonRegion-title" id="main_details_heading">Main Panel</h2>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-12 ">
<div class="t-ButtonRegion t-Form--floatLeft t-ButtonRegion--noPadding t-ButtonRegion--noUI" id="other_details" role="group" aria-labelledby="other_details_heading">
  <div class="t-ButtonRegion-wrap">
    <div class="t-ButtonRegion-col t-ButtonRegion-col--left"><div class="t-ButtonRegion-buttons"></div></div>
    <div class="t-ButtonRegion-col t-ButtonRegion-col--content">
      <h2 class="t-ButtonRegion-title" id="other_details_heading">Details</h2>

      <div class="t-ButtonRegion-buttons"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="t-ButtonRegion-col t-ButtonRegion-col--right"><div class="t-ButtonRegion-buttons"></div></div>
  </div>
<div id="divide" style="margin: 5px 5px 15px; padding: 20px 15px 20px 20px; **position: fixed;** background-color: rgb(222, 239, 251);"><h3 id="header1">B.2.1</h3><p id="paragaph1">Organizational system for the environmental program that defines staff roles and responsibilities, etc,etc </p></div></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
      <div class="t-ButtonRegion-buttons"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="t-ButtonRegion-col t-ButtonRegion-col--right"><div class="t-ButtonRegion-buttons"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I starred the two spots that if removed would fix the issue of the divide element not appearing on the screen. Not both, either one or the other. I needed a fix position so i removed the floatLeft. Would anyone know why this floatLeft class would cause the divide element to not show. Note: only time this occurs is in IE, Firefox and chrome work fine with the above code. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I looked for the css after the suggestion and got:

```
.t-Form--floatLeft{overflow:hidden}
.t-Form--floatLeft .col{width:auto!important}
.t-Form--floatLeft .t-Form-fieldContainer{width:auto;float:left;clear:none}
.t-Form--floatLeft .t-Form-labelContainer{min-width:0;width:auto}
.t-Form--floatLeft .t-Form-inputContainer select{max-width:100%}
```

I have more to go off of now, so I am researching still but if anyone has ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Without the CSS it's pretty hard to comment.

Comment: I will check that, thanks.

Comment: Am I seeing it right that you have 2 nested regions? Both have template buttonregion? Have you tried to switch the template around? What apex version is this?